# Tagging ROS questions with versions

Tags: discussion, tags

As we consider supporting more of the ROS traffic here. One of the important elements is to know what version of ROS you're using.

On answers.ros.org we actually require a ROS version tag to make sure that we have a hint towards what version they're using. Since this forum is not ROS specific and the ROS codenames cannot be required I've been thinking of a way to tag things a little bit more clearly. To that end I've been considering doing tags like:

`ros-<DISTRO>` for each `<DISTRO>` aka `ros-kinetic`, 'ros-melodic' or `ros-humble` etc

There's also what we refer to as [Upstream Distributions](https://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages). For these I'd like to suggest. `ros-upstream` and the user would also be expected to declare the upstream distribution `focal` `jammy` `bullseye` `fedora-32` etc.

And lastly my understanding is that we can setup an alias for tags. And I'd propose that the straight `ros` tag be setup to alias to a very explicit `ros-version-undeclared` that we can set the description to say, please declare your tag version explicitly.

Does this sort of tagging system make sense here?

One side note is that I have explicitly not called out ROS 1 vs ROS 2. The codenames are specific enough to capture that, and in the long run ROS 1 will be fading back and always typing `ros2` will become redundant. Alternatively we could put the number into the tags, but I feel that it's easier not to have it in the middle of the name. As the tag names here will echo the standard paths to `/opt/ros/<DISTRO>...` and the package names `ros-<DISTRO>-packagename`

**Update 2023-06-14**

After the below discussion I've updated the proposal with a PR here:https://github.com/osrf/se_migration_tags/pull/1

At the high level. I've triaged it down to the top ~1000 tags with about 10 or more usages in ROS. It's also sorted now for easier browsing. And a bunch of deduplication too.

It also reverts the no-version-declared and adds 'ros' to the tag mappings explicitly for the ros ones.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds reasonable to me.  But some thoughts:

What I find most helpful about tags is the ability to subscribe to a tag or "watch" a tag.  For example I watch `roomba` and `irobot-create` among others.  Currently, I doubt there is a way to have wildcards in your watched tags.  Or have a hierarchy of tags.  For example I imagine you would want to watch all of `ros-*`.  It might become a pain to have to add to your watch list each time a new distro is announced.

I know each distro is different.  But I'm sure there are many things that apply to multiple distros.  There is a limit of if think 5 tags on a question.  So we should not expect people to have multiple distro tags.

I guess I am just a little wary of per-distro tags being a little too specific.  Keep in mind that most questions require lots of details (that are not tags) in order to adequately answer.  For example: which version of Roomba or Create do you have?  There could easily be tags for `roomba-500-series`, `roomba-600-series`, `roomba-700-series`, `irobot-create1`, `irobot-create2`, `irobot-create3`, etc.  But people *usually* provide this info in the question anyway.  And are quick to add it when asked.

How much benefit will distro tags provide you as opposed to having the distro in the text?

Comment: We've found that people don't tend to declare their distro in questions regularly. We had to implement that the all packages are required to tag a distro so that is not the first question asked for clarification every time. We can't do that here as there might not be ROS questions but by having the handful of explicit tags it can be useful. And if we use a tag synonym to push short `ros` tags to `ros-version-undeclared` it becomes very obvious to the user that they've not stated the version. Versus thinking that they've told us everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the distro tags are useful since it provides an extra chance for the poster to provide that information when creating the question. When adding tags if I type in `ros` then I will also see the distro-specific tags come up, and I would be inclined to select the one I'm using.

The issue then, as Ben points out, is if I'm interested in answering ROS questions then I have to be mindful when new distros are released and watch the new tags. One way to mitigate this is to try to enforce that when someone uses a `ros-<DISTRO>` tag, they also use the `ros` tag (or `ros2`, I'm not sure how the `ros`/`ros2` distinction will play out). This would be similar to the usage of the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag on stackoverflow where the tag guidance is if you use the `python-3.x` tag, then always additionally use the `python` tag.

Also because there is a notable difference between ROS1 and ROS2 distros, the `ros-<DISTRO>` tag immediately informs me whether the user is in ROS1 or ROS2 irrespective of the other tags they provide. I might be a ROS1 expert, but I might not be of much help with a ROS2 question if I've never used it since many things are radically different. Having that extra info in the tag very quickly informs me what the poster is working with, and I don't have to try to piece it together from the question.

Comment: 'stackoverflow where the tag guidance is if you use the python-3.x tag, then always additionally use the python tag.' That's in contravention of the tagging policy that bans meta-tags https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0):

One of the big benefits of tags vs. a strict hierarchical ontology is that one can combine tags, so I really don't see much of a downside in tagging ROS questions with both `ros`/`ros2` *and* a distro-specific tag if the question warrants it.

One thing to keep in mind with tags is their longevity: Will a frequent or high-rated question tagged `ros-foxy` really be irrelevant for anyone trying to fix the same problem in ROS 2 Iron? I suspect in most cases the answer is no. And in the rare cases where it actually is yes, the question should be tagged with only `ros-foxy` and not also `ros2`.

I think it is ontologically wrong to assume that `ros-foxy` implies `ros2`. Of course, Foxy is a ROS 2 release, but if a person decides to tag a question `ros-foxy` rather than just `ros2` then that implies a level of specificity that he or she intended to express and which is therefore significant in the context of the question.

Another argument is simplicity: people come to StackOverflow and Robotics.SE for help. They may not even know which ROS distro they are using.

Comment: A lot of this was focused on avoiding the meta-tag avoidance policy. It would be much easier to just bring across the bare names. We could just do `ros` in general and `ros-foxy` to indicate the version. I'd be happy with that.

Comment: I've been trying to find that meta-tag avoidance policy but failed. Do you have a pointer?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging See the heading "Avoid meta-tags"

Comment: Thanks. In my read it actually doesn't apply to what we want here. I think `ros` and `ros2` pass both of those tests, i.e., they *can* be used by themselves, and they are not subjective. In fact, there is plenty of precedent on the main StackOverflow. Just look at `react` questions that are also tagged `javascript`. I think this is roughly analogous to what we are discussing here.

Comment: Similarly, if you search for `angular` in the SO tags (https://stackoverflow.com/tags), you'll see `angular` but also `angular5`, `angular7`, etc.

Comment: Ok, with that as a decent reference I'll update the suggested tagging policy.

Comment: Update posted above and at https://github.com/osrf/se_migration_tags/pull/1