# Tagging ROS package names

Tags: discussion, tags

Similar to [Tagging ROS questions with versions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/tagging-ros-questions-with-versions) if we're looking at more volume of ROS questions. Historically on answers.ros.org we've recommended that people tag questions with the name of the ROS package. Is that appropriate here? There will be a significant influx of tags and some of the tags may collide with other usages if the names are moderately generic. But with the [ROS naming conventions](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0144.html) requiring descriptive names I think that the number of collisions should be minimal.

Any objections to planning to use the packages names verbatim as tags? And this would go with the versioned ros tag from [Tagging ROS questions with versions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/tagging-ros-questions-with-versions)

Answer (score 0):

This proposal I am a little less fond of.  I think it will create an explosion of mostly little used tags for all but maybe a handful of the popular packages.

Lots of my [concerns with distro tags](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1445/110) are the same here.  With too-specific tags, they loose their usefulness.

But maybe I haven't thought through the types of ROS specific questions on this site.  If people are reporting bugs in a package, then maybe we need specific tags.

Of course the creation of tags is pretty easy.  It only takes 150 reputation and can be done by anyone.  So in some ways we can let this happen organically.

Comment: In general for ROS Answers the package tags have been the critical element to get the right person able to review it.  We ask that authors/maintainers subscribe to their package's tags. We also have the ability to render the filtered questions onto our site for better visibility [such as here](https://index.ros.org/p/roscpp/github-ros-ros_comm/#noetic-questions)