# Migration of content from ROS and Gazebo Answers Scheduled!

Tags: discussion, ros-migration, announcement

Based on the feedback we received from [past posts](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/feedback-on-migrating-ros-and-gazebo-answers-sites-to-robotics-se), we have begun the migration of ROS and Gazebo Answers to Robotics Stack Exchange.

Starting August 11th, we will be redirecting all ROS and Gazebo Answers users to begin using Robotics Stack Exchange as their primary ROS Q&A resource.  In the coming days and weeks there will be an influx of new users to Robotics Stack Exchange. We kindly ask that you patiently help them learn about Robotics Stack Exchange,  the features it offers, and our community’s best practices.

### Planned Migration Timeline

- On August the 11th, [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org) and [answers.gazebosim.org](http://answers.gazebosim.org) will be changed to read-only mode and we will begin the export process.
- On August the 15th, we expect the migrated questions to land on [robotics.stackexchange.com](http://robotics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Will there be links from the migrated answers.ros.org questions to their copies here?  That could help a lot with seo, would be helpful to anyone who does end up on answers and has a new comment or edit or would otherwise post a duplicate question.

Comment: We have the full mapping of original question to the ones posted here. We are going to be setting up redirects on those questions to make it even better for users to not even get a "copy" but land on the new version. And that should also be better for search indexing too.