# Has answers.gazebosim.org also been migrated to here?

Tags: discussion, ros-migration, gazebo-migration

Related to [my answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/110191/9176) to [Clear difference between /reset_world and /reset_simulation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/110177/9176), the (slow loading) page [difference between reset_simulation and reset_world](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/24566/difference-between-reset_simulation-and-reset_world/) states in the top banner

> The site is read-only. Please transition to use Robotics Stack Exchange

Here is a screenshot of that page (to save loading time)

> [image: Screenshot of webpage]

However, I can not find that particular question, even doing a "google site search"<sup>1</sup>:

> [`site:robotics.stackexchange.com "difference between reset_simulation and reset_world"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A%2F%2Frobotics.stackexchange.com%20%22difference%20between%20reset_simulation%20and%20reset_world%22)

That search only shows the recently asked question, linked to above (that I tried to answer).

So, in short, was the site migrated, and if so, why can't I find that particular question?

Or is the banner just a "manual re-direct", and no actual migration of the historical Q&A took place?

---

<sup>1</sup> Which are, IMHO, *usually* more effective than the in-house search mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question as you've discovered the site was migrated. However only questions which met a certain threshold were migrated. In general if nobody had upvoted a question or answer to indicate that it was valuable it was omitted in the migration.

We are building a statically hosted archive of the site that will be easier to keep the information available into the future. And it will redirect to the stack exchange version.

It looks like that question I'm not sure why that question might not be available. Stack Exchange does prune older questions without votes or being accepted or might have been auto pruned without any up vote here.

Comment: Hmm, the question didn't seem to be a candidate for [auto-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions), as it had an answer with two uovotes (the answer doesn't need to be accepted). Someone might have downvoted it (twice) I guess. I wonder if a number of other questions might also get deleted and "lost" to the roomba, if it considers them to be abandoned (when in fact they aren't really)... Or, like you say, maybe that *particular* question hadn't been migrated. Ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The problem is that the upvotes and downvotes couldn't transfer officially on the migration. You'll see that the upvotes are only in the description of the migrated content not in the stack exchange voting. This was a compromise because the upvotes on migration couldn't be moved without having the (up/down) voters associated with every vote. And we didn't have universal user associations to support that.

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't realise, or rather I hadn't really thought it through. Yeah, I guess it makes sense, as we can't have "ghost": voters/users. That's a shame. TBH, the whole migration sounds a bit of a headache :-)

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Migration of content from ROS and Gazebo Answers Scheduled!](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/9176), I see that the content of [answers.gazebosim.org](https://answers.gazebosim.org) *was* also migrated.

Therefore, I can only assume that the migrated question that I am looking for was deleted (for whatever reason) and is no longer visible - which is a bit of a shame.

So, it is quite lucky that the old site is still up, and that the old question (and answer) is still visible.

I know that answers shouldn't have follow up questions in them, but that does beg the question: How long will the old site be up for, and how long will *all* the old questions *still* be visible?